# Jetty Java websocket client doesn't connect to server

Tags: eclipse, websocket, jetty

I am using Java Jetty client written [websocket-client 9.3.8.RC0]. Websocket server is little wierd in our case. 
   It accepting request in format.
        wss://192.168.122.1:8443/status?-xsrf-=tokenValue

Token Value is received in first Login POST request in which i get Token Value & Cookie header. Cookie is added as a header whereas token is given as a param.
Now question is : - 
   When i run below code it just call awaitclose() function in starting. But there is not other function called i.e. Onconnected or even Onclose.

Any help would be appreciated to debug it further, to see any logs or environment issue to see why Socket is not connected.

Trying to figure out following points to debug. 
1. To check if client certificates are causing issue.

Tried with my python code wspy.py it work seemlessly fine.

Code is

```java
public final class websocketxxx {

WebSocketClient client=null;
public websocketxxx (){

}


public void run(String host,String cookieVal, String xsrfVal, String resource) throws IOException {

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setTrustAll(true);
    WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(sslContextFactory);
    MyWebSocket socket = new MyWebSocket();
    try {
        client.start();
        ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        // Add the authentication and protocol to the request header
        // Crate wss URI from host and resource
        resource = resource + xsrfVal;
        URI destinationUri = new URI("wss://" + host + resource); // set URI
        request.setHeader("cookie",cookieVal);
        request.setHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "ao-json");
        //System.out.println("Request Headers print : "  request.getHeaders())
        System.out.println("Connecting to : " + destinationUri);
        client.connect(socket, destinationUri, request);
        socket.awaitClose(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@WebSocket
public class MyWebSocket {
    private final CountDownLatch closeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {
        System.out.println("WebSocket Opened in client side");
        try {
            System.out.println("Sending message: Hi server");
            session.getRemote().sendString("Hi Server");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Message from Server: " + message);
    }

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        System.out.println("WebSocket Closed. Code:" + statusCode);
    }

    public boolean awaitClose(int duration, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return this.closeLatch.await(duration, unit);
    }
}

public Client getBypassCertVerificationClient() {
    Client client1 = null;
    try {
        // Create a HostnameVerifier that overrides the verify method to accept all hosts
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String host, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        // Create a TrustManager
        TrustManager[] trust_mgr = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String t) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String t) {
                    }
                }
        };
        // Create the SSL Context
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trust_mgr, new SecureRandom());
        // Create the client with the new hostname verifier and SSL context
        client1 = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .hostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier)
                .build();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return client1;
}

public String[] simple_Login_POST_request(String host, String user, String password, String resource, String data) {
    String resp = null;
    String[] headers = new String[2];

    try {
        // Create a Client instance that supports self-signed SSL certificates
        Client client = getBypassCertVerificationClient();

        // Create a WebTarget instance with host and resource
        WebTarget target = client.target("https://" + host).path(resource);

        // Build HTTP request invocation
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request();

        // Encode the user/password and add it to the request header
        invocationBuilder.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        Form form = new Form();
        form.param("userid", user);
        form.param("password", password);
        // Invoke POST request and get response as String
        //post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));

        Response response = invocationBuilder.method("POST", Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));
        resp = (String) response.readEntity(String.class);

        // Print input URL, input data, response code and response
        System.out.println("URL: [POST] " + target.getUri().toString());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status: " + response.getStatus());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status: " + response.getHeaders());
        headers[0] = response.getHeaderString("Set-Cookie");
        //response.getStringHeaders()
        headers[1] = response.getHeaderString("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        System.out.println("Response: \n" + resp);

        response.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return headers;
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String host = "";
    String user = "";
    String password = "";
    String resource = "";

    host ="192.168.122.1:8443";
    user = "ADMIN";
    password ="ADMIN";
    websocketXXX wsNotification = new websocketxxx();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Simple POST LOGIN Request 
    resource = "/api/login";
    String headers[]=  wsNotification.simple_Login_POST_request(host, user, password, resource, null);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    headers[0] = headers[0].substring(headers[0].lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
    System.out.println("headers[0]: " + headers[0] + "\n");
    String cookie = headers[0];
    String XSRFToken = headers[1];

    resource = "/status?-xsrf-=";
    //wsNotification.simple_websocket_example(host, cookie, XSRFToken, resource);
    wsNotification.run(host, cookie, XSRFToken, resource);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is mostly correct.

Setting raw `Cookie` and `Sec-WebSocket-*` headers [is forbidden](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.11.v20160721/jetty-websocket/websocket-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/ClientUpgradeRequest.java#L51-L68), you have to use the API.

**Cookie handling from:**

```java
ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
request.setHeader("cookie",cookieVal);
```

To [`ClientUpgradeRequest.setCookies()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/UpgradeRequest.html#setCookies-java.util.List-) :

```java
ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
List<HttpCookie> cookies = new ArrayList<>();
cookies.add(new HttpCookie(...));
request.setCookies(cookies);
```

> Note: if you are using the java [`CookieStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieStore.html), then you can pass the CookieStore instance to the client as well, using the [`setCookiesFrom(CookieStore)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/ClientUpgradeRequest.html#setCookiesFrom-java.net.CookieStore-) method.

**Sub Protocol Selection from:**

```java
ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
request.setHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "ao-json");
```

To [`ClientUpgradeRequest.setSubProtocols()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/UpgradeRequest.html#setSubProtocols-java.lang.String...-):

```java
ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
request.setSubProtocols("ao-json");
```

Comment: Tried following code as per your changes but it didn't help for anything. No onConnected() method is called. Here is snippet of changes **************************URI destinationUri = new URI("wss://" + host + resource); // set URI
   List<HttpCookie> cookies = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
   cookies.add(new HttpCookie("Cookie", cookieVal));
   request.setCookies(cookies);
         request.setSubProtocols("ao-json");
   
   System.out.println("Connecting to : " + destinationUri);
   client.connect(socket, destinationUri, request);

Comment: Add the `@OnWebSocketError` handler and see if you get some kind of error being reported via the websocket layer.

Comment: Problem right now is cookie header Below is SSH handshake prints after remove hexadecimal code   : no-cache..Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: ao-json Cookie: Cookie ="-http-session-=4::http.session::78c7ec010a4845e5457c91546e91c3; path=/; secure; httponly"...       See this  Cookie header its absolutely wrong. Trying to Correct it now

Comment: Use the java.net.HttpCookie API properly, don't just shove your cookieVal into it without a regard to what a Cookie value is.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Your hint to add the error handler should really be one of the answers, not a comment. This really helped me figure out a similar issue (my websocket endpoint returned a 400, which would not show anywhere else but in the error handler).